# Barplot doesn't seem to sort my df correctly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

my dataframe is:

```
b1_df1_c.sort_values('score_s', ascending=False).head()

score   score_s
CountryCode     
Denmark 9.20    1.000000
Luxembourg  7.85    0.956297
Netherlands 6.52    0.913241
Czech Republic  5.69    0.886371
Belgium 4.96    0.862739
```

my barplot:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,20))
plt.title("Tolerance (scaled)",family='Serif', weight='bold', size=20)
ax = sns.barplot(x='score_s', y=b1_df1_c.index, data=b1_df1_c)
```

[image]

with highest scores for: Austria, Average, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus
instead of Denmark, Luxembourg, Netherlands etc.

Does anybody have an idea why it sorts values so wrong?

Comment: Add `inplace = True` or assign the result of `sort_values` to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Is the datatype of score_s actually numeric?   Could be sorting by something other than the actual float value.

EDIT: I think Ben is correct.  You are not saving the sorted version of the DataFrame.